# Analysis - Continuity of composite functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I have just started learning about continuity and discontinuity of functions, and came across this question, and I'm not quite sure how to tackle it :

### Prove OR disprove: If $f$ is discontinuous at $x$ = x<sub>0</sub>and g is continuous at $f$($x$<sub>0</sub>), then $g ◦ f$ is discontinuous at $x$<sub>0</sub>.

My thoughts:

I have seen and shown before that if $f$ is continuous at $x$<sub>0</sub> and $g$ is continuous at $f$(x<sub>0</sub>), then $g ◦ f$ is continuous at $x$<sub>0</sub>.

So I began thinking about definitions of continuity/discontinuity.

Since $g$ is continuous at $f$($x$<sub>0</sub>), we have $\forall$$\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t $|f(x)-$$f$($x$<sub>0</sub>$)|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|g(f(x))-$$g(f$($x$<sub>0</sub>)|$<\epsilon$

Also $f$ is discontinuous at $x$<sub>0</sub>:

$\exists \epsilon>0 s.t. \forall \delta>0, \exists x \in$ R s.t. $|x-$$x$<sub>0</sub>|$<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f($$x$<sub>0</sub>$)| \geqslant \epsilon$

So by g is continuous we have $|f(x)-f($$x$<sub>0</sub>$)|<\epsilon$, and then I am not sure how to proceed to show that $|g(f(x))-g(f($$x$<sub>0</sub>$)|\geqslant \epsilon$. or in fact $|g(f(x))-g(f($$x$<sub>0</sub>$)|< \epsilon$

I will be very thankful if anyone can give me some pointers on how to solve this problem! Many thanks!

Comment: Are they both discontinuous by hypothesis?

Comment: actually I typed the question wrong

Comment: it shoulda been that f is discontinuous and g is continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. Take $f$ to be any discontinuous function. Now take $g(x) = 0$ for any $x$. Then $g \circ f(x) = 0$ for every $x$ and is thus continuous.

Comment: thanks so much ! I think I understand now!